# Problem with an observable that uses a second API

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, store

Well here I am really bad with RxJs and I am facing a problem.

In one of my Angular component I load data like this:

```
this._obs$.push(this.store1.loadTypes());
this._obs$.push(this.store2.loadLimitQuantities());
// [...]
    
forkJoin(this._obs$).subscribe(
  next => console.log(next),
  error => console.log(error)
);
```

One of the observables receives data from API 1 and then needs to retrieve data from API 2 from the data received from API 1:

```
loadLimitQuantities(): Observable<LimitQuantity[]> {
    // API 1
    const obs = this.limitQuantityService.getLimitQuantities().pipe(share());
    obs.subscribe(data => {
        if (data) {
            const ifs = [];
            data.forEach(element => {
                // API 2
                ifs.push(this.technicalAttribTextIFSService.getType(element.ifsType).pipe(take(1), tap((type) => { 
                    type ? element.type = type.valueText : element.type = null;
                })));
            });
            forkJoin(ifs).subscribe(end => {
                this.limitQuantitiesSubject.next(data);
            });
        } else {
            console.error("Erreur lors du chargement des quantités limites");
        }
    });
    // AP1
    return obs;
}
```

Unfortunately the `next` of my Angular component which loads the data is received too early because API 1 has finished returning the data but not API 2.

How to do ? The `return` should be at the `forkJoin` of API 2.

**StackBlitz :** [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-problem-with-an-observable-that-uses-a-second-api)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got your problem 100% - but I think this will get you what you need.

```
limitedQuantitiesWithTypeFromApi2$ = this.loadLimitQuantities()
    .pipe(
        switchMap(
          x => forkJoin(x.map(y => this.getType(y.ifsType))), 
        ),
      );

  ngOnInit() {
    forkJoin(this.loadTypes(), this.limitedQuantitiesWithTypeFromApi2$)
      .subscribe(([types, lq]) => console.log('Original 1', types, lq));

    forkJoin(this.loadTypes(), this.loadLimitQuantities())
      .pipe(
        map(([types, lq]) => {
          return lq.map(x => ({
            ...x, 
            type: types.find(y => y.ifsType === x.ifsType)
          }))
        })
      )
      .subscribe(x => console.log('Alternate Approach', x));

  }

  loadTypes() {
    return timer(1000).pipe(
      map(x => ([
        { ifsType: 1, type: 'vText1'}, 
        { ifsType: 2, type: 'vText2'}
      ])),
      share()
    );
  }

  loadLimitQuantities() {
    return timer(1000).pipe(
      map(x => ([
        {ifsType: 1, type: null, }, 
        {ifsType: 2, type: null }
      ])),
      share(),
    );
  }

  getType(ifsType: number) {
    return timer(1000).pipe(
      map(x => ifsType === 1 ? 'vText1' : 'vText2'),
      map(x => ({ ifsType, type: x })),
      share()
    );
  }
```

However, I think it's safe to assume that your API2 is an HTTP call - and while it would work, I would advice to just batch fetch all the "type-associations" so you can just make a simpler stream.

I mean if `loadTypes` already has an `ifsType` to `type` associaction then you can just do the "Approach 2" subscription - and if you're using angular anyway, you can just use the `async` pipe to subscribe to `loadTypes` and `loadLimitedQuantities`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helps me a lot, on the other hand the data must be pushed into a subject so that my components can subscribe to it,
so i add a method which changes the store data instead of returning it directly in the alternate approach.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need something like that?

```
class MyClass {

    loadLimitQuantities(): Observable < LimitQuantity[] > {
        // API 1
        return this.limitQuantityService.getLimitQuantities().pipe(
            map((data) => this.getTypeRequests(data)),
            switchMap((requests) => forkJoin(requests))
        );
    }

    getTypeRequests(data) {
      if(!data) {
          console.error("Erreur lors du chargement des quantités limites");
          return [];
      }

      return data.map(element => this.getType(element));
    }

    getType(element) {
        return this.technicalAttribTextIFSService.getType(element.ifsType)
            .pipe(map((type) => ({...element, type: type ? type.valueText : null})))
    }
}
```

You get limit quantites, map them to type requests, and then join them together.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but at no point is the data pushed into the subject `this.limitQuantitiesSubject.next(data)`.
Also, I have build errors with `loadLimitQuantities()` and I would have liked to keep them all within the same function.

Comment: Do you need push your data to the subject after element type Observables resolved ?

Comment: Yes, since the load functions (`loadObjects()`) are only executed once
and the result is to push in a subject of the store so that my components can subscribe to it
(`private objectsSubject = new BehaviorSubject <Object[]>([]); public objects$ = this.objectsSubject.asObservable();`).